# Lua Class keeping old values

Tags: lua

I'm new to Lua so I'm sure I'm missing something but I have this class and it seems to be behaving unexpectedly.

```
Item = {elm = nil, __index = {}}

function Item:new(obj)
    setmetatable({}, Item)
    self.elm = obj.elm
    return self
end


function Item:collectItem()
    print(self.elm);
end

local itm = Item:new{elm = "val1"}
local itm2 = Item:new{elm = "val2"}

itm:collectItem()
itm2:collectItem()
```

This outputs:

```
>val2
>val2
```

When I would expect:

> val1
>   val2

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here in that your `Item:new` function keeps modifying the same table: Item (`self` in the context of `Item:new`).  What you want to do is create a new table for each new Item object you create.  Here is one way you can do this:

```
Item = {elm = nil}

function Item:new(obj)
    -- Create a new table whose metatable's __index is the Item table
    local instance = setmetatable({}, {
        __index = self
    })
    -- Modify the new table, not Item (self)
    instance.elm = obj.elm
    -- Return the new object
    return instance
end
```